# Javascript for-loop not checking entire list

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this for-loop that is meant to find existing items in a list of items. This should then help to grow a list of unique items.

The issue is that my loop works fine for a subset of the list, but fails when I process the entire list. This subset was taken from the actual data.

Here is the offending function:

```
/**
 * Check whether the Id is already written to the list.
 * @param {String} id Item to check.
 * @param {[String]} list List to check string in.
 */
function isIdIncluded(item, list) {
  let foundFlag = false;

  for (const existing of list) {
    if (
      existing && (
        existing === item
      )
    ) {
      foundFlag = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return foundFlag;
}
```

And then the result:

```
Processed 24 raw documents to 12 breaches in small sample.
Processed 4154 raw documents to 4154 breaches for actual sample.
```

I have tried using forEach, filter, and find but switched to the traditional for in the hope that this will be more synchronous.

Much appreciated!

Comment: It's not super clear, may be the input data and expected output may help. You're "breaking" from the loop so it won't process the whole loop.

Comment: I cannot find any wrong part with given information. Maybe you'd better to share more code or data which you used.

Comment: if a string in your array is allowed to be an empty string, and you're searching for an empty string, this won't find the empty string due to the `existing &&` check (as an empty string is falsy)

Comment: Probably a better idea to use a `Set` for this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The check for `existing` is just a precaution and there should not be empty strings in the list.

I'll also switch to using sets and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: If you're able to find a small example of an array of strings which doesn't for your function then that would be a good thing to add to your question. At the moment your code seems like it should be functioning correctly

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` worked perfectly thanks. So this is then what I have now:

```
/**
 * Check whether the item is already written to the list.
 * @param {String} item Item to check.
 * @param {Set} list List to check string in.
 */
function isItemIncluded(item, list) {
  return list.has(item);
}
```

And the result:

```
Processed 4154 raw documents to 2077 breaches for actual sample.
```